# Renaming the package that R.java is generated in

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I am using eclipse and I created a test android project and the package in the "gen" folder that contains `R.java` is currently called `com.something.test` (I thought I was just testing but build my whole app on it!)

This is referenced when loading the app and the phone sometimes displays it so I need to rename it.  I tried this by clicking refactor but it regenerated it again with the old name!

Can I rename it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think you have to change the application's package name in the manifest (then rebuild).

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Right click your project, then Android Tools -> Rename Application Name:

[image]

Or, if you want to do it manually, go to your manifest file, change the package name, and make a Project Clean.

Comment: I just Refactor -> Renamed my project, and Eclipse did not change the package name in Manifest.  Thanks for your second answer!!

Comment: I followed these steps but then I got a problem because it didnt fix the package in the manifest (just in case someone else has the same problem)

Answer (score 23):

Check the `AndroidManifest.xml`, there's a `package` attribute on the `<manifest>` top-level element. That is where `R.java` is generated and you should be careful renaming it.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old question, but I needed it now and maybe someone else needs it too.
I'm using Android Studio 2.1.1

To make it work I had to change:

- package - on AndroidManifest.xml
- applicationId - on build.gradle of the app folder

This way there was no need to import *R* on every java class.

**It is important to remember that this is not an usual change and should not be done every time.**

The link [applicationId vs. package name](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) explains the difference between them and why they should not be changed.

Answer (score 3):

For those who attempt to manually change it, the statements that the R.java file is linked is correct.  If you simply change it in the manifest, you will get a long sequence of "R cannot be resolved" errors throughout your java files that reference resources.  To correct that you'll need to add an import for the R class in each of those files.

So if you had your package originally as: "com.mycomp.myapp.android" and changed it to "com.mynewcomp.myapp.android" you would need to go into each java class file and add:

`import com.mynewcomp.myapp.android.R;`

If you run the originally suggested rename command on the project this is done for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

It gets named to the root package of your app.  If you change your app's root package to something else, R.java will exist in that package now.

Comment: This is incorrect, it's set by android:package which is different to root package

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to check is if you have custom Views with xml namespaces. It took me a minute to realize I had to change the xmlns attribute.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myxmlnamespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mynew.packagename"
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored my package one by one using Right Click->Refactor and Android Manifest.XML. My R file was still building on the old package name.

Closing and Opening the project fixed this issue, but I needed to go and do a manual change on all my java files.